# What is use of StringReader in a program?

Tags: java

Where can it be used effectively?
Instead of creating an object of reader class, the developer can simply use string to extract the data. So what is the purpose of using StringReader class.

Comment: Well, parsers which expect `Reader` as inputs, for example.

Answer (score 3):

`StringReader` extends `Reader`. So you can test parsers and alike without touching an actual file or something.